# TYPO3: custom extension - "The extension name must not be empty" error

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have upgraded TYPO3 version from 9 to 10. But my custom extensions throwing

```
(1/1) #1239891990 InvalidArgumentException
The extension name must not be empty
```

error while I am trying to re-activate those.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your extension for the usage of one of these methods:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin()
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin()
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule()
```

Most probably you have to search in `ext_localconf.php`, `ext_tables.php`or any file in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides`.

The first parameter of each of these methods is the extension name (in UpperCamelCase) or the extension key (in lower_underscore). This is missing according to your error message.

Maybe your extension relies on `$_EXTKEY`. Starting with TYPO3 10 LTS the variable `$_EXTKEY` isn't filled with the extension key anymore. Solution: use the hardcoded extension key within `ext_tables.php` and `ext_localconf.php`. See the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationFiles/Index.html#rules-and-best-practices) for details.

Comment: Thank you @peter you solution saved my day